# Event Emitters in NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to Nodejs and I am learning from code snippets downloaded from net. I have a basic question in chat application code.

Below is the code from app.js (server side)

```
var stream = collection.find().sort().limit(10).stream(); // collection coming from mongoDb
stream.on('data', function (chat) { 
          socket.emit('chat', chat.content); 
});

socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
  // code to add into mongoDB
}
```

The above code, get records from mongoDB and emits the data which is captured in client side and also a function which listens if a data pushed from client to get inserted in to DB.

Client side code -

```
var socket = io();
$('#send-message-btn').click(function () { // this is a button
    var msg = $('#message-box').val();
    socket.emit('chat', msg);
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
    $('#message-box').val('');
    return false;
});
socket.on('chat', function (msg) {
    console.log('adding to message div '+msg);
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
});
```

Now my question is, socket.emit in app.js is been captured by `socket.on` method in `client.js` and `socket.emit` in button lick function in client side is captured in `socket.on` in server side.

How that works ? Why the app.js's socket.emit is not captured in `socket.on` method inside app.js and same client js's emit method is not captured in client ja's `socket.on` method.

Answer (score 0):

socket.on listens for messages arriving from the other side.

Basically when you do `socket.emit('chat', chat.content);` you should specify which user to send it to.

You have few options, or you keep a list of sockets somewhere, where you can find them based on sessionId/username or whatever. or you can use callbacks.

client.js

```
$('#send-message-btn').click(function () { // this is a button
var msg = $('#message-box').val();
socket.emit('chat', msg, function(res) {
    console.log('adding to message div '+msg);
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
);
$('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
$('#message-box').val('');
return false;
});
```

and in the server

```
socket.on('chat', function (msg, cb) {
    var stream = collection.find().sort().limit(10).stream(); // collection coming from mongoDb
    stream.on('data', function (chat) { 
         cb(chat.content); 
    });
});
```